Do Apsaras have sex with Devas in Devaloka?
As far as I know, Apsaras are one of the Upadevas. There are ten types of Upadevas, namely - Vidyadhara, Apsara, Yaksha, Rakshasa, Gandharva, Kinnara, Pisaca, Guhyaka, Siddha and Bhuta.
Gandharvas are the musicians of Devaloka, whereas Apsaras are dancers.
It is true that sometimes Apsaras are sent to the mortal world to disrupt the austerities of Sages. In those cases, they do have sex with the Sages. I am not talking about that. I am interested to know their role in Devaloka. Are they just dancers? There is a popular notion that Apsaras are the prostitutes of Devaloka. Is that true? Is it based on any scriptural reference? Is there any reference in scripture that indicates Apsaras have sex with Devas?

The Amarakosha (1।1।52।1।1) gives the meaning:

स्त्रियां बहुष्वप्सरसः स्वर्वेश्या उर्वशीमुखाः। घृताची मेनका रम्भा उर्वशी च तिलोत्तमा। सुकेशीमञ्जुघोषाद्याः कथ्यम्तेऽप्सरसो बुधैः। हाहा हूहूश्चैवमाद्या गन्धर्वास्त्रिदिवौकसाम्.।

They are the Veshyas of the Deva loka.

Can you please add the online link to Amarakosha?

Yes, at least I found two occasions where Apsaras were having sexual intercourse with Devas.
Siva Purana, Rudra Samhita, Kumara Khanda, Chapter 1

When Shakra was engaged in intercourse with Rambha, Durvasa, the great Indra among sages, separated them.


When Kama was engaged in intercourse with Ghritachi, Guru restrained him.

So, Apsaras are dancers and at the same time prostitutes of heaven.

Apsarās aren't prostitutes, by calling them so, you are literally disrespecting them. Please don't impose Abrahamic mentality on the Hindu framework by saying so. Apsarās are mānanīya devīs of devaloka, not veśyās.

@Bingming if someone has sex with multiple partners by definition she is a prostitute. It does not matter what you think.

Actually the bodies of the residents of devaloka are different due to which they're endowed with mystic potencies. By human calculation, one can call them something only as per one's perception.
